# pygame with turtle crashing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, turtle-graphics

I get this error code:

```
2017-04-13 03:04:14.958 Python[606:839244] -[SDLApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1007a0dd0
2017-04-13 03:04:14.971 Python[606:839244] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SDLApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1007a0dd0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d71be7b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffa22fbcad objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d79dcb4 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d68dfb5 ___forwarding___ + 1061
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8d68db08 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Tk                                  0x000000010324b5e6 TkpInit + 471
    6   Tk                                  0x00000001031c6c8d Tk_Init + 1794
    7   _tkinter.cpython-36m-darwin.so      0x00000001027e7dfd Tcl_AppInit + 77
    8   _tkinter.cpython-36m-darwin.so      0x00000001027e5849 _tkinter_create + 889
    9   Python                              0x000000010006a688 _PyCFunction_FastCallDict + 568
    10  Python                              0x00000001000f33e4 call_function + 612
    11  Python                              0x00000001000f8d84 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 21892
    12  Python                              0x00000001000f27a0 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2720
    13  Python                              0x00000001000f2fab fast_function + 219
    14  Python                              0x00000001000f33cb call_function + 587
    15  Python                              0x00000001000f8d84 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 21892
    16  Python                              0x00000001000f37cc _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 828
    17  Python                              0x000000010000e984 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 356
    18  Python                              0x000000010000eaa0 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 208
    19  Python                              0x000000010000e5b3 PyObject_Call + 99
    20  Python                              0x0000000100089871 slot_tp_init + 81
    21  Python                              0x0000000100080144 type_call + 212
    22  Python                              0x000000010000e8d4 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 180
    23  Python                              0x00000001000f3225 call_function + 165
    24  Python                              0x00000001000f8d84 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 21892
    25  Python                              0x00000001000f37cc _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 828
    26  Python                              0x000000010000e984 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 356
    27  Python                              0x000000010000eaa0 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 208
    28  Python                              0x000000010000e5b3 PyObject_Call + 99
    29  Python                              0x0000000100089871 slot_tp_init + 81
    30  Python                              0x0000000100080144 type_call + 212
    31  Python                              0x000000010000e8d4 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 180
    32  Python                              0x00000001000f3225 call_function + 165
    33  Python                              0x00000001000f8d84 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 21892
    34  Python                              0x00000001000f312e fast_function + 606
    35  Python                              0x00000001000f33cb call_function + 587
    36  Python                              0x00000001000f8d84 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 21892
    37  Python                              0x00000001000f27a0 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2720
    38  Python                              0x00000001000f3636 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 422
    39  Python                              0x000000010000e984 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 356
    40  Python                              0x000000010000eaa0 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 208
    41  Python                              0x000000010000e5b3 PyObject_Call + 99
    42  Python                              0x0000000100089871 slot_tp_init + 81
    43  Python                              0x0000000100080144 type_call + 212
    44  Python                              0x000000010000e8d4 _PyObject_FastCallDict + 180
    45  Python                              0x00000001000f3225 call_function + 165
    46  Python                              0x00000001000f8d84 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 21892
    47  Python                              0x00000001000f312e fast_function + 606
    48  Python                              0x00000001000f33cb call_function + 587
    49  Python                              0x00000001000f8d84 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 21892
    50  Python                              0x00000001000f27a0 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2720
    51  Python                              0x00000001000f2944 PyEval_EvalCode + 100
    52  Python                              0x000000010012f21e PyRun_FileExFlags + 206
    53  Python                              0x000000010012f4bf PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 447
    54  Python                              0x0000000100148ada Py_Main + 3914
    55  Python                              0x0000000100000dfe Python + 3582
    56  Python                              0x0000000100000c34 Python + 3124
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Abort trap: 6
```

My code is

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/


import sys;
import log;


# Initialization
print(log.GetTime());

import pygame;
import turtle;


pygame = pygame;
turtle = turtle;

# After Initialization
pygame.init();
turtle.begin_fill();

player = {
    'speed': {
        'move': 5,
        'rotate': 1
    }
};

while true:
    time = log.GetTime();
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed();

    if keys[K_ESCAPE]: break;
    if keys[K_W]: turtle.forward(player.speed.move);
    if keys[K_S]: turtle.backward(player.speed.move);
    if keys[K_A]: turtle.left(player.speed.rotate);
    if keys[K_D]: turtle.right(player.speed.rotate);

print('Ended program!');
```

I am very very new to python programming, and have no experience in what this is. I have tried looking for answers to fix this, but quite hard when I don't know what's wrong, could anyone tell me how I could fix the issue? What did I do wrong?

Comment: How are you running the code? Why is it in `#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/`? Probably put it in a regular folder, like `~/Dev/MyProject/myprogram.py` and run it with `python myprogram.py` from that folder.

Comment: Also, `while true:` is not legal code. You need to post functioning code, not pseudo-code.

Comment: This code contains many problems, please fix them...and btw, what is `log`? where did you get it? the `log` from pypi does not have a `GetTime()` method. As a side note, you **do not** need semicolons at new of lines, it just make it look less python.

Comment: @bananafish Because that is where all of the modules are stored

Comment: @abccd log is a module I have created myself. The function simply outputs: 'HH:MM:SS'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I will point out your mistakes and how to solve your problem.

1. `true` is called `True` in python
2. `K_ESCAPE`, `K_W`... isn't defined, I don't know where you got your names from but you gotta figure that out yourself. You probably meant `pygame.K_ESCAPE`, `pygame.K_w`...note: they are lower cased
3. python does not require `;` at every line breaks
4. you do not need `pygame = pygame` and `turtle = turtle` since the import comes with the names
5. getting item from dict uses [] not .
6. calling turtle's left/right turns the cursor by that angle not move left/right

And here's how you can stop it from crashing:

```
import sys
import log


# Initialization
print(log.GetTime())

import pygame
import turtle


# After Initialization
turtle.begin_fill()
pygame.init()


player = {
    'speed': {
        'move': 5,
        'rotate': 1
    }
};

while True:
    time = log.GetTime()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]: break
    if keys[pygame.K_W]: turtle.forward(player['speed']['move'])
    if keys[pygame.K_S]: turtle.backward(player['speed']['move'])
    if keys[pygame.K_A]: turtle.left(player['speed']['rotate'])
    if keys[pygame.K_D]: turtle.right(player['speed']['rotate'])

print('Ended program!')
```

You will need to swap places with `turtle.begin_fill()` and `pygame.init()` since both pygame and turtle uses the base module `tkinter`, but only one `Tk()` (the window) is allowed at a time, but turtle does not know how to use the existing window that pygame created, so the app crashed. While pygame knows how to use the existing window turtle created.

As a side note, it's not necessary to use pygame with turtle, just use `tkinter` and it has way more functionalities. Plus, you don't even need either of them, turtle have enough functions to do what you wanted.

EDIT: pygame and turtle will *never* work well together. recommend using tkinter.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I decided to make my program in node.js cause' I am more familiar with JavaScript!